# Trying to use values from other cells to create the arguments to build an array

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

`=ARRAYFORMULA(('Main'!c9)!((e1):(e1)))`

`'Main'!C9`  is a dropdown menu that was hand populated with tab titles.

`e1` acquires the row number from a string search

I'm looking to build an array using just the values from the row with the searched string, on the page from the dropdown.

very specifically, it's in the formula tab in c9 on
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cxrnloPDH8jUcUyMixr1r6u83MjOMGbsaTP4VPNjY9Y/edit?usp=sharing

Ive been all through the help docs and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood correctly, but maybe it is the indirect function you are after ?

```
=indirect(Main!C9&"!"&E1&":"&E1)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Don't have enough reputation to vote up.